# PHP regexp how to catch }} at the end of the pattern

Tags: php, regex

I spend few hours above the regexp in php and I really dont know how to do it.
I have a code like this:

```
    $content = 'xxxxxxx{{ $aaa = $aaa->bbb("bbb/{$ooo->id}") }}xxxxxxx';

    $content = preg_replace_callback('/{{ *(\$[^}]+ *)+ *}{2}/', function ($m) {
        var_dump($m);
        return str_replace(['{{', '$', '}}'], ['<?php echo ', '$this->', '?>'], $m[0]);

    }, $content);
```

The problem is in the `}{2}` part of the pattern. If I remove it everything works  well. When I push it to the end regexp does not match the string. What is the problem with that `}{2}`? I need to catch also the }} in the string.

Comment: Did you mean `{{ *(\$[^}]+ *)+ *}"\) }{2}` ? You are trying to match 2 times `}`, but you first have to match `") ` before it.

Comment: Perhaps even a non-greedy match `{{ *(.*?) *}}`?

Comment: Yes, [the `{{\s*(\$.*?)\s*}}` regex](https://regex101.com/r/tbaaiL/2) [should work for you](https://3v4l.org/Y9U8a).

Comment: Thanks guys. Ungreedy modifier works as I expected.